# convert strtotime to date time format in php

Tags: php

i need to convert strtotime to date btime format (from 1307595105 to 06/08/2011 09:51:45 PM PDT) in php

Could you please give me an answer

Comment: http://php.net/strtotime and for formatting the date, http://php.net/date - the information is all there.

Answer (score 84):

```
$unixtime = 1307595105;
echo $time = date("m/d/Y h:i:s A T",$unixtime);
```

Where

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: i worked me, and to output in format date: date("Y/m/d", $time);

Answer (score 20):

```
<?php
  echo date('d - m - Y',strtotime('2013-01-19 01:23:42'));
 ?>       
Out put : 19 - 01 - 2013
```

Comment: That's not even the question that was asked .

Answer (score 10):

Use [date()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php) function to get the desired date

```
<?php
// set default timezone
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

//define date and time
$strtotime = 1307595105;

// output
echo date('d M Y H:i:s',$strtotime);

// more formats
echo date('c',$strtotime); // ISO 8601 format
echo date('r',$strtotime); // RFC 2822 format
?>
```

Recommended online tool for strtotime to date conversion:

http://freeonlinetools24.com/

Answer (score 5):

```
FORMAT DATE STRTOTIME OR TIME STRING TO DATE FORMAT
$unixtime = 1307595105;
function formatdate($unixtime) 
{ 
        return $time = date("m/d/Y h:i:s",$unixtime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is exp.

```
$date_search_strtotime = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));
echo 'Now strtotime date : '.$date_search_strtotime;
echo '<br>';
echo 'Now date from strtotime : '.date('Y-m-d',$date_search_strtotime);
```