# Get Date from Datetime String

Tags: php

This is my String **Tue, 20 Aug 2013 10:45:05**
and i want to this string in Date Format Like this :

**2013-08-20**.

Guys Please help.

Thanks

Comment: you could find this by little goggling .here your answer in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297544/convert-strtotime-to-date-time-format-in-php  .stack-overflow is not about spoon feeding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$d=date('Y-m-d',strtotime('Tue, 20 Aug 2013 10:45:05'));
echo $d;
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('Tue, 20 Aug 2013 10:45:05'));
```