# strtotime back to DateTime

Tags: datetime, strtotime

I'm sending a DateTime (2015-09-07T06:30:00+02:00) thru an url to an other page.

I've been adviced to do:

```
$eventDateStr ="2015-09-07T06:30:00+02:00";
$s = strtotime($eventDateStr);

....
echo '<a href="second.php?'.$s.'">Link</a>';
```

**In the second page**

This gets me to the second page where I get the variable.

```
$s =$_GET['s']; //Gives 1441600200
```

Is there a way to convert the variable ($s)from strtotime back to dateTime Atom format? This is to be used after and to be used in a variable.

Comment: DateTime is a class in php (http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)  This question is confusing at first because that's not exactly what you're trying to do.  You're still dealing with basic string date formats not data types.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert strtotime to date time format in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297544/convert-strtotime-to-date-time-format-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$unixtime = 1307595105;
echo $time = date("m/d/Y h:i:s A T",$unixtime);
```

Taken from: [convert strtotime to date time format in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297544/convert-strtotime-to-date-time-format-in-php)

Comment: That gives me not really the same. 2015-09-07 06:30:00 AM UTC

Comment: In my case I changed the code to                                                          $time = date("Y-m-d\Th:i:s\+02:00",$unixtime); This worked like it should.

Comment: Yeah you have to adjust the syntax, it was just about the function itself. Glad I could help.